# Loop through JSON, store some keys in other JSON object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am receiving a JSON object from a POST, and need to store some of the keys and values inside another JSON object which i will then return to the calling function.

I would like to do this in the most efficient way possible.

The first JSON object looks like this:

```
"Details": [
  {
    "Id": "124b00016c96d7",
    "Name": "Bob",
    "schedule": [
      {
        "time": 1420515000,
        "value": true
      }
    ],
    "mod": false
  },
  {
    "Id": "124b00016ca144",
    "Name": "Jonas",
    "schedule": [
      {
        "time": 1420515000,
        "value": true
      }
    ],
    "mod": true
  }
  ]
}
```

I now want to loop through it and take the ID and Name and store it in a new object like so:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "label": "Bob",
      "value": "124b00016c96d7"
    },
    {
      "label": "Jonas",
      "value": "124b00016ca144"
    }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

All help appreciated :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
var dataArray = data.Details.map(function(detail) {
    return {value: detail.Id, label: datail.Name}
});

var newObject = { data : dataArray };
```